# Issue regarding Thread.Sleep() for 2hours in c#

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2012, sleep

I am working on .net windows application.

I am using `System.Threading.Thread.`

In a single form using five(5) threads. I have a code which when run, it executes series of lines in sequence. I would like to add a pause in between.

For that i am using

```
Thread.Sleep(10800000)
```

of 3 hours

But I checked in debug mode, after executing line of

```
Thread.Sleep(10800000)
```

My debug not goes to next line or next line never executes even after waiting for 4 hours.

I am using this Thread.Delay in other thread not in main thread.
This delay requires because, i send a command to configure setting to a hardware, that setting requires minimum **3 hours** to complete.

That's why i am using this

```
Thread.Delay(10800000)
```

Means my onward code is proceed only after waiting for 3 hours.

Can any one help me?

Comment: That's your problem - using `Thread.Sleep` for 2 hours. Thread.Sleep isn't a scheduling mechanism, it's meant to freeze a thread for a *short* time and allow other threads to proceeed. If you have to wait for 2 hours, use a timer, `Task.Delay` (which uses a timer itself) or use the operating system's Scheduled Task. You don't need to set the timer to the full 2 hours, you can set a shorter interval and increase a counter up to the time you need. Or save a target time in a field and check it each time the timer fires

Comment: @MehdiKebdani: So? 10800000 is in milliseconds. `3 * 60 * 60 * 1000 = 10800000`

Comment: @MehdiKebdani 10,800,000 milliseconds is 3 hours.

Comment: Sorry i didn't end my answer but pressed enter key :/

Answer (score 5):

Thread.Sleep is not designed for long sleeps. You should consider using somthing like [System.Threading.Timer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.timer(v=vs.110).aspx).

> Provides a mechanism for executing a method on a thread pool thread at specified intervals.

You can give it a first run time of midnight, and have it go off every 24 hours. the Timer(TimerCallback, Object, TimeSpan, TimeSpan) constructor is exactly what you are looking for.

Comment: What's your suggestion if i use " System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(new TimeSpan(0, 0, 10800)); " instead of Thread.Sleep(10800000)?

Comment: I don't think the timer would be much different the Sleep method, unless you begin to deal with short intervals (e.g. one minute), then use a counter to trigger whatever you need.

Answer (score 1):

One would argue that even using a timer is not the best tool for the job.  You may want to consider using **Windows Task Scheduler** (TS) instead.  With TS, you can setup a schedule to say run your app and carry out the workflow, or if your program must run all the time, trigger another process that communicates with your app somehow.

If the **process** is **not doing anything** until the next interval then it's best to just simply **kill the app**.  That way you won't be **wasting threads or processes** twiddling their thumbs over exorbitant delays waiting for the next interval to do something.

You can use the *Microsoft Task Scheduler v2 COM Library* from c# to setup your schedules or do so manually from the TS UI itself.